# Google Calendar: how to retrieve a series that contains exceptions

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm working on a client using the Google Calendar API, and I need to retrieve the full series of a recurring event.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances does that for pristine, unchanged series. Sending the `eventId` and some optional params like `timeMin`, `timeMax` and `maxResults` I get an iterable containing each instance in the series.

The problem is when the user edits one or more events in the series. When saving the changes a prompt asks for either apply the changes to the whole series, to only that instance or to that one and all following instances.

When you select one of the last two options, the series is literally converted into two distinct series: the original one is edited (`UNTIL` is shortened) and a new series is created with the instance or instances removed from the original series.

My question is how to retrieve the full original series starting from the `eventId` of one instance after the series has been modified/split.

Comment: Hi there! The approach to this situation changes based on the modification done by the user. Could you please define the changes in the event? After those modification are delineated you could find the original series by using [`Events.list()`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) with common parameters (that is all those parameters that weren't

Comment: Modifying any attribute splits the original series. Per https://developers.google.com/calendar/recurringevents#modifying_all_following_instances, modifying the name, location, description... creates a new series and modifies the original one. The only property that seems to relate them is the new `seriesMasterId` starts with the `seriesMasterId` of the primitive series, plus a low dash and a timestamp (example original series is `110sbu8gh796d1eovum9dnen0d`, split series is `110sbu8gh796d1eovum9dnen0d_20201229T010000Z`). But `Events.list()` can't search by partial match on `seriesMasterId`.

Comment: If you know the previous ID, you could list the events and interact with the response until you find all the events (one per each split plus the original one). Would this be a valid workaround in your setup?